# Problems in implementing WkPagesCollectionView Multi Tab Library IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, tabs, uiwebview

I am using [WKPagesCollectionView](https://github.com/adow/WKPagesCollectionView) library for Multi tab feature for UIWebView like Safari Multi Tabs for IOS.

I have 2 problems while using this library.

1. As the view is loaded all the various tabs are visible. I want to load only one tab when the view is loaded like in Safari where when the view is loaded only one tab is visible.
2. When multi tabs are present, I can still touch collection view cell item for example if I create search bar in collection view the user is still able to interact with search bar. What i want is to stop the user interaction with the collection view cell when multi tabs are visible.

You can also answer on the [Github Page](https://github.com/adow/WKPagesCollectionView/issues/7)  of this library where I have asked the same question.

Thanks in advance.